# How to merge folders logically like Desktop folder in Windows 10/11

Tags: windows, merge, junction

As you know the Desktop in Windows is created merging contents of **\Users\Public\Desktop** and **\Users<User>\Desktop**.

So is it possible to create same effect. What I want is a central **Pictures** directory which has the pictures in *d:\Pictures*, *e:\Pictures* etc... But the content of those folders should remain in their respective drives. Only when I look at the **Pictures** directory, I should see those files/folders in other drives also. I know there is a mklink command which could create a symlink/junction to those files but that doesn't work because you should keep linking any new files on those folders.

The folder name is example. As far as I know there are ways to do this for special folders.

I remember that this was possible and I did do it in the past. But I forgot how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is called a Library in Windows. There is already a library called Pictures, so you can simply right-click on every folder you want included and select "Include in library", then select the Pictures library. You can also create a new library in that last step.

Comment: That's well and good but as I explained in my message this allows me to add the main folder in the library. What I want is everything under this "main" folder appear in the "Library" not the folder itself. Anything added to this folder also should appear automatically in the Library.

Comment: That... is exactly what a library does, unless I'm missing something in your question. When you click on the library, you will see all the files present in any of the folders you added to the library. You won't see the individual folders you added, just the files (and any subfolders in those folders).

Comment: It didn't cover what I wanted entirely because sorting the folders under library still remembers the drive names too, so it doesn't break grouping to sort the folders correctly. But at least I could still find the folder I want by typing the first few letters.